# Swift : Dropbox image upload fails due to RegEX pattern match failing

Tags: ios, swift, dropbox-api

I am using SwiftyDropbox API to upload images to dropbox. I have image in project directory and trying to upload it like this :

```
    // Verify user is logged into Dropbox
    if let client = Dropbox.authorizedClient {

        let imagePath : NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("abc", ofType: "png")!
        print("Path :--> \n", imagePath)
        let url : NSURL = NSURL(string: imagePath as String)!

        client.files.upload(path: "", body: url).response{response, error in


            if let metadata = response {
                print("*** Upload file ****")
                print("Uploaded file name: \(metadata.name)")

                self.delegate?.imageSavedSuccessfully()
            }
            else{
                print(error!)
            }

        }
```

And the error I get is (including screenshot too.):

```
 precondition failed: " must match pattern "\A(?:/.*)\z":
```

[image]

Any hint or guide what I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your file upload, you're specifying the path `""`, but that represents the root folder, not a file path.

Instead, the path should be the full path where you want to upload the file, including the file name. For example, to upload the file as "abc.png" in the root of the Dropbox account, you'd specify the path as `"/abc.png"`.

Comment: Ugh. I guess I read somewhere that mentioned providing `""` will upload it to root folder. But thanks a lot. Appreciate a quick answer!

Comment: No problem. For reference `""` is used to represent the root folder, but only in cases where that is accepted as a valid value, e.g., when listing root as a folder.

Comment: The file upload function is telling you to use an empty string as the path? Can you post details as a new question?

Comment: My bad. I actually forgot to append filename to parameter `path` and in log it said to use empty string. Maybe that log message wording can be changed. In short i did `client.files.upload(path: "/", body : .....)` instead `client.files.upload(path: "/" + fileName , body: .....)`

Comment: Oh I see. It seems we have some overly broad check that looks for "/" as root, to try to be helpful and let the developer know to use "" for root. That doesn't make sense in the context of uploading files though. We'll get that cleaned up. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah. When I told you very first time that I saw somewhere which mentioned providing empty string `""` for root folder, it turns out it was log message. Thanks and you're welcome.